# Raw string literals and file codification

Tags: c++, c++11, string-literals, rawstring

C++11 introduced the [raw string literals](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#raw-strings) which can be pretty useful to represent quoted strings, literals with lots of special symbols like windows file paths, regex expressions etc...

```
std::string path = R"(C:\teamwork\new_project\project1)"; // no tab nor newline!
std::string quoted = R"("quoted string")";
std::string expression = R"([\w]+[ ]+)";
```

This raw string literals can also be combined with encoding prefixes (`u8`, `u`, `U`, or `L`), but, when no encoding prefix is specified, does the file encoding matters?, lets suppose that I have this code:

```
auto message = R"(Pick up a card)";         // raw string 1
auto cards = R"()"; // raw string 2
```

If I can write and store the code above, its obvious that my source code is encoded as unicode, so I'm wondering:

- The `raw string 1` would be a unicode literal? (though it only uses ASCII characters), in other words, does the raw string inherits the codification of the file where is written or the compiler auto-detects that unicode isn't needed regardless of the file encoding?
- Would be necessary the encoding prefix `U` on the `raw string 2` in order to treat it as unicode literal or it would be unicode automatically due to its contents and/or the source file encoding?

Thanks for your attention.

EDIT:

Testing the code above in ideone.com and printing the demangled type of `message` and `cards` variables, it outputs `char const*`:

```
template<typename T> std::string demangle(T t)
{
    int status;
    char *const name = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), 0, 0, &status);
    std::string result(name);
    free(name);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto message = R"(Pick up a card)";
    auto cards = R"()";

    std::cout
        << "message type: " << demangle(message) << '\n'
        << "cards type: " << demangle(cards) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> `message type: char const*`
>
> `cards type: char const*`

which is even most weird than I thought, I was convinced that the type would be `wchar_t` (even without the `L` prefix).

Comment: This part of the standard is quite murky. In GCC and MSVC I believe the string will just be the bytes between the quotation marks.

Comment: @Simple "*the string will be the bytes between the quotation marks*" so... this would imply the source file encoding :O

Answer (score 1):

Yes it matters, even to compile your source. You will gonna need to use somenthing like `-finput-charset=UTF-16` to compile if you are using `gcc` (the same thing should apply to VS).

But I IHMO,  there are something more fundamental to take into account in your code. For example, `std::string` are containers to `char`, which is 1 byte large. If you are dealing with a UTF-16 for instance, you will need 2 bytes, so (despite a 'by-hand conversion') you will need at least a `wchar_t` (std::wstring) (or, to be safer a `char16_t`, to be safer in `C++11`).

So, to use Unicode you will need a container for it and a compiling environment prepared to handle your Unicode codifided sources.

Comment: The `raw literal 1` and `raw literal 2` aren't stored into any container, they're stored in deduced type variables. I did that way in the example 'cause I was not sure about which kind of `std::basic_string` would be the best choice.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I think your observation is very important. I am gonna test it!

Answer (score 1):

Raw string literals change how escapes are dealt with but do not change how encodings are handled. Raw string literals still convert their contents from the source encoding to produce a string in the appropriate execution encoding.

The type of a string literal and the appropriate execution encoding is determined entirely by the prefix. `R` alone always produces a `char` string in the narrow execution encoding. If the source is UTF-16 (and the compiler supports UTF-16 as the source encoding) then the compiler will convert the string literal contents from UTF-16 to the narrow execution encoding.