# how to insert extended ascii characters in string?

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I am making Latin-Croatian translator in C++. My problem is that I can't print string with characters like 'š','č','đ' etc, that exist in croatian. So is there a way to input extended ascii characters in string and then output them on screen without using solutions like this one: cout << "String that includes a \x9C sign"; // \x9C is '£'?

Comment: You might need to use a different codepage. Probably using unicode would serve better than ASCII for your purposes.

Comment: If your system is using utf8: std::cout << "\u00A3\n";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisrt of all, you should be clear about source codification, there some discussions around SO about it (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460700/raw-string-literals-and-file-codification)).

If you are in an C++11 environment, you can use `char16_t` or `char32_t`, which are granted to handle chars 16 and 32 bit long, respectively (take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)). So if you sure all characters can be handled in 16 bits (UTF16), char16_t can be an alternative. AFAIK, `wchar_t` is not granted to handle 2 bytes (at least at VS 2005/2008 it is).

To handle `UTF-8`, I strong believe that the best alternative if to use [codecvt](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/codecvt/).